# Error during compilation is department_id invalid identifier

Tags: sql, database, rdbms, concept

```
create table student 
(
    Student_id number(30), 
    student_name varchar(30), 
    city varchar(30), 

    constraint pk primary key(student_id), 
    constraint department_id 
        foreign key(department_id) references department(department_id) 
);
```

Comment: You haven't defined a department_id field in your student table

Comment: Can you list what the error is?

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS This is going to be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a `department_id` in your `student` table you cannot refer to it as key.

Add a  `department_id` column in your `student` table with the same data type as in your `department` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
create table student 
(
  Student_id number (30), 
  student_name varchar(30), 
  department_id int,
  city varchar (30), 
  Constraint pk primary key(student_id), 
  constraint department_id foreign key(department_id) references department (department_id) 
) ;
```